# Why it is possible to redefine Var (given that in FP values are immutable)?

Tags: clojure

I am using Counterclockwise to run a REPL, but I noticed this on Leiningen too.

I can call def to define a var twice. For example,

```
=> (def a 1)
#'fractal.core/a
=> a
1
=> (def a 2)
#'fractal.core/a
=> a
2
```

Clojure is a Functional Programming language and in FP objects are supposed to be immutable. If I can do this in what sense a is immutable?

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not changing value of Var, it is so called *rebinding* (think *shadowing* in imperative languages).

Comment: @om-nom-nom This is nothing like shadowing. You can call it rebinding if you like, but there's no particular difference between this and changing the value of the var; yes, the var still has the same "value" in that it's still holding the same mutable cell it used to, but the contents of that cell have changed and that's what is usually meant by changing a thing's value.

Answer (score 13):

The entire point of vars is that they can be rebound, hence the name: var -> variable.

From the [docs](http://clojure.org/vars):

> Clojure is a practical language that recognizes the occasional need to maintain a persistent reference to a changing value. ... Vars provide a mechanism to refer to a mutable storage location that can be dynamically rebound (to a new storage location) on a per-thread basis.

You are not changing any immutable value by rebinding a var.

Think of it of just giving an immutable value a name, and later give another immutable value that name.

Answer (score 5):

re -`def`ing a var (that is, setting the root binding, as opposed to temporary/thread-local  re-binding) is mostly intended to be a tool for development. Since standard global functions and values (those defined with def/defn) are var-based, you can redefine them without having to restart the clojure program you're editing.

Note that vars are *not* values, they're explicitly intended to be *mutable references to* values/functions.

Answer (score 2):

> in FP objects are supposed to be immutable.

This is incorrect.

*Pure* functional programming requires variables to be immutable values.
However, Clojure is not a purely functional language, and allows untracked side-effects anywhere.

The majority of functional languages are impure, in this regard, as they do not track the occurence of side-effects, such as mutation, in the language itself.

Comment: It isn't incorrect in the sense that in FP you *should* make objects immutable and use pure functions as much as possible. The fact that you *can* mutate state in an impure FP language like Clojure does not imply that this is good practice.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what the OP meant by "supposed"